# working with stripslashes in php+mysql (query)

Tags: php, mysql

Working fine in MySQL:

```
UPDATE post SET rec_d = replace(rec_d,'\\','')
```

But not fine in PHP:

```
$db->query("UPDATE post SET rec_d = replace(rec_d,'\\','')");
```

I'm also trying /\/...

How do i properly compose a query?

Comment: Hint: What is \\ inside a double-quoted string?

Comment: nothing, mysql will replace \ with nothing.. \ needs to be escaped with a special character \\

Comment: No, \\ becomes \, which means you need \\\\ if you want \\ in the final query.